# Get substring by parsing from both directions

Tags: python, string

I have string with a lot of  `'` character and need to extract a substring of it:

```
str = "There is' 'some' Text', and' EXTRACT ME'a'n'd' even' more' 't'ext"
```

I would like to get the substring after the 5th occured `'` from left and the 8th `'` from right (backwards) so that the result would be:

```
result = " EXTRACT ME"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name; that masks the built-int `str()` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string from the left or the right, applying a limit to the number of splits using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
result = inputstring.split("'", 5)[-1].rsplit("'", 8)[0]
```

Note the second argument limiting the split to the first `n` occurrences counting from the left or the right, respectively.

Demo:

```
>>> inputstring = "There is' 'some' Text', and' EXTRACT ME'a'n'd' even' more' 't'ext"
>>> inputstring.split("'", 5)[-1].rsplit("'", 8)[0]
' EXTRACT ME'
```

Comment: I first thought of parsing it but split and rsplit is the right way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A bit longer solution which doesn't create temporary list or string objects:

```
s = "There is' 'some' Text', and' EXTRACT ME'a'n'd' even' more' 't'ext"
i = -1
for _ in xrange(5):
  i = s.find("'", i + 1)
  assert i >= 0
j = len(s)
for _ in xrange(8):
  j = s.rfind("'", i, j)
  assert j >= 0
print repr(s[i + 1 : j])  #: 'EXTRACT ME'
```

Answer (score 1):

This one can be handy too:

```
inputString = re.sub("^([^']*'){5}(.*?)('[^']*){8}$", "\\2", inputString)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the string contains newlines. ^, $ and . has to be changed to fix it.

Comment: My guess is that this is much slower for long strings than the other solutions.